# Else loop statement not shown when program reads blank space

Tags: java

I would like the user to enter "Stuff he/ she would like to do" and when the program reads a blank space/ no input it will display "breaking out of loop" I've played around the if loop statement and it wouldn't display "breaking out of loop".

```
do {
    System.out.print("Type in stuff you would like to do: ");
    String stuffToDo = input.nextLine();

    if (!" ".equals(stuffToDo)) {
        ++n;
        ToDo.add(stuffToDo);
    } else {
        System.out.println("breaking out of the loop");
        break;
    }
} while (input.hasNext());
break;
```

Comment: My guess is you are not entering a line with exactly one space in it. Try checking for an empty string.

Comment: I've tried it with 1 open space, and my program wouldn't display "breaking out of loop"

Comment: @DarelLow What is an "open space"?

Answer (score 1):

`" ".equals(stuffToDo)` check that `stuffToDo` consist from single whitespace.

I assume you want `"".equals(stuffToDo)` instead.

If you use `"".equals(stuffToDo.trim())` it will work with any number of whitespace symbols. Consult Java dock for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to change

```
if (!" ".equals(stuffToDo))
```

to

```
if (!stuffToDo.trim().isEmpty())
```

This way any empty input or no input would stop the program.

`trim()` - will remove all white characters from beginning and end of input

`isEmpty()` - will return true, if input is empty

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this program. When you type exactly one space you get a String with one space in it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        if ("".equals(s))
            System.out.println("You typed a blank line");
        else if (" ".equals(s))
            System.out.println("You typed one space");
        else
            System.out.println("You typed '" + s + "'");
    }
}
```

prints

```
You typed a blank line

You typed one space
hi
You typed 'hi'
```